# Сортировка в Closure Table

Tags: php, mysql, дерево

Привет! Можно ли сделать сортировку (напр. по полю position), и привести к иерархии с помощью SQL в MySql. Или, нужно, выводить все дерево и уже в PHP - это делать. Если вас не затруднит, приведите, пожалуйста, пример, как это можно сделать в PHP.

Comment: Приведи SQL код как ты таблицу получаешь

Comment: Вы не знаете как в php массив сортировать?